# Error "signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR)" while loading Pytorch model in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, pytorch, segmentation-fault, image-classification

I have a code in my app where it should load my Pytorch model using LiteModuleLoader.load(). The code is not mine and I have just started to learn more about Android app development using Java.

```
    Module model;
    void LoadTorchModule(Context context,String fileName) {
        File modelFile = new File(context.getFilesDir(), fileName);

        try {
            if (!modelFile.exists()) {
                InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(fileName);
                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(modelFile);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[2848];

                int bytesRead = -1;
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }

                inputStream.close();
                outputStream.close();
            }
          
            model = LiteModuleLoader.load(modelFile.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When I tried to build my app. This error shows up in Logs and I could not really tell what is the problem.[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzHcw.png)

Additionally this is my gradle build.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.hbcv'
    compileSdk 33

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hbcv"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation project(path: ':opencv')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation 'org.pytorch:pytorch_android_lite:1.10.0'
    implementation 'org.pytorch:pytorch_android_torchvision_lite:1.10.0'
}
```

Then, this is the link for my model (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PCFR5P-p5T2tRD2Ej5ZfO2pCJJ_0g-yk/view?usp=sharing). This is a classification model, that can identify disease of a chicken using fecal images and it can identify 4 classes, which are healthy, cocci, salmo, and ncd.

I have tried some solutions online, but still it does not work for me. Then, I try to somehow debug it. I found out that if I comment out this, the error goes away. However, this render me unable to use the model.

```
model = LiteModuleLoader.load(modelFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

This problem is also happens when I use Module.load() from Pytorch mobile.

I also check the path of the model and it seems correct to me.